# Send Response vom Server to Client

Tags: reactjs, postman, nestjs

I have a question. I know the procedure when doing a Post or Get from the Client to the Server. But is it possible to do a Response, or send a response back, when I'm doing a Post or Get from Postman.

I'm using Postman to fill my Database with a CSV File. When the Table is created and filled I need the created ID in my Client.

Is there a way to do this.

So when I POST with Postman, I need the created ID stored in my client for later use.
Is it maybe possible to save the ID in the URL so I can then use it?

Comment: What do you mean? You can modify the Response object to return whatever you want. And you can also do the same thing with the route itself to point to the specific unique id.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard hey, yes I know that the reponse can be modified.
I need the ID from the Response in my client. I only know how to do this when I do a Post from my Client. 
But this is different. I do the POST from Postman, and If i do a response, then the response will just get to the Postman and not to my client

Comment: Ah, got it. Yes, there is a way to do it. Take a look here-> https://blog.postman.com/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/

Comment: @mutantkeyboard thank you. I'll have a look at what you sent me with extracting the data from response. But when the ID is saved in a Postman global variable, can I use it from my client?

Comment: You can't do it that way. You can only export the whole environment from Postman as a JSON. But what you can do is either write a similar code for your client, or you could create a separate table in the database after CSV import that will store all the ID's, and provide a get function for your client to fetch unique ID's from that particular table. This probably isn't the smartest solution, but if something else comes to my mind, I'll post it here.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard thank you for the help. I looked into what you've sent me and I think I've found the good Solution.
When doing the Post with Postman, I return the needed ID and save it in a Global Variable. Then when doing the next API Request where I need the ID, I can just call it, and pass it to the Backend.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard ok, i just realised that i was thinking the wrong way. My solution won't work because the API Requests aren't going through Postman when I'm sending them from my client so I can't access the global variable that I've just set.